# Suitable microphone for IO pins

Tags: audio

I am using the IO pins of the Pi to drive a speaker and a microphone.  The speaker is easy to find, just a cheap one from [Cool Components](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/66mm-64ohm-speaker.html) however I am finding it harder to find a suitable microphone.

It just needs to be able to receive sin waves made by the speakers.  Any suggestions?  It's for a project for school group.

*Update*

A telephone pickup seems like a  cheap, sound receiving option.

Comment: Awesome project. How do you play sound to the speaker using GPIO?

Comment: @ppumkin, nothing clever, just sending them high and low and using a transistor to source the current.

Comment: Cool! Here is something about microphone- maybe you saw it already  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/can-i-get-audio-input-through-the-gpio

Comment: Hi, there is a new Digital I2S MEMS Microphone Breakout: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout that outputs digital audio data. No analog conversion required!

Comment: @Vladislav Great find.  Cheers.

Comment: btw, I'm not sure, but probably it's possible to connect Bluetooth handsfree and use its microphone. It needs to be tested.

Comment: And there is a nice new Mini USB Microphone, that works via USB on Raspberry Pi: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3367

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight problem with using an `sine` wave microphone because it is Analog signal. 
All the GPIO pins on the Pi are digital. So you will have to use a A2D (Analag to Digital) helper.

If there were some Analogue pins then you could use [this Arduino project](http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/experiments/arduino-realtime-audio-processing/) to help you out with the schematic.

[image]

In order to use a normal everyday microphone (from an old phone even) you will need to use a A2D processor like the `MCP3008` . It gets more complicated though as you need to use SPI to read the values into something sensible.  [There is an answer this Exchange already talking about how to try and use a microphone with that chip.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4810/894)

The last resort is to buy a USB microphone or sound card instead. You buy one as cheap as £2.50 called the [CM802](http://www.meritline.com/usb-sound-adapter-channel-volume-control-mute-switch---p-60824.aspx) <sup>[*REF](http://asliceofraspberrypi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/adding-audio-input-device.html)</sup> or a more professional one from for about £20 called the [Sound Blaster Play!](http://uk.creative.com/p/sound-blaster/sound-blaster-play) <sup>[*REF](http://www.g7smy.co.uk/?p=283)</sup> Once you plug that in you will get new audio input and output in the `alsa-mixer` utility.

[How to use the MCP3008 without bitbanging and using hardware SPI of the Pi](http://jeremyblythe.blogspot.ca/2012/09/raspberry-pi-hardware-spi-analog-inputs.html)

Comment: It'll be a square wave really.  Thanks for the advise on the CM802.  I hadn't considered the digital\analogue problem.  Do you really think there'll be a problem with a wave at a 50% duty cycle?

Comment: I am not enitrly sure to be honest but it could work if it is a sqaure wave. You might be able to read it as digital data on the GPIO pins but I am not sure what how you going to process that data. You will need the voltage to be 1.7v+ so the PIN reads high with a max of 3.3v - Then you also get the rising and falling edge criteria that are set within the GPIO but that is more important for data and specific BAUD.